# Setup Ruby environment based on date or Ruby version

Tags: ruby, date, rubygems, version

For testing purposes, I want to install a Ruby environment based on a past date. For instance, Ruby 2.5.0p0 came out in 2017-12-25 and somewhere I read that Rails 5.2.6 is the version to use with it. What I want is a programmatic way to know what version/date of a gem should go with what version of Ruby. Am I missing some super easy way to do this?

Edit:

My idea to test in a Ruby environment that would have existed at a certain date seems to be intractable and is possibly unnecessary. So what I will do is run through a few major Ruby releases and install their [best Rails versions](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) and let all the other gems float to whatever versions get dragged in.

```
Ruby    Rails
2.5.0   5.2.6
2.5.9   5.2.6
2.6.7   6.0.3.7
2.7.3   6.0.3.7
3.0.1   latest
```

Comment: Rails maintains an official list of supported [Ruby Versions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions) for each major Rails version.

Comment: This is based on an false assumption that there only is one version on a gem to go with a certain version of Ruby. Thats not really how reality works - instead what you can get by using bundler or the rubygems.org API is a list of compatible gem versions for a given version of Ruby.

Comment: @max, can you provide an example line of code for generating a "list of compatible gem versions for a given version of Ruby"?

Comment: @oaklodge If you look at a [random gem on `rubygems.org`](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri), you might see it says something like: `REQUIRED RUBY VERSION: >= 2.5.0`. This information is used by `bundler` then installing dependencies for a project.

Comment: In other words, **for example**, you cannot use ruby 2.4 with nokigiri 1.11.7. But you also don't need to know/care which is the latest version of nokogiri to support ruby 2.4, because bundler will figure that out automatically for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is a programmatic way to know what version/date of a gem
> should go with what version of Ruby.

One way of doing this would be to use [the API provided by RubyGems.org](https://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/):

```
# run with ruby get_versions.rb gemname rubyversion

require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'pp'

gemname = ARGV[0] || 'rails'
uri = URI("https://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/#{gemname}.json")
target_ruby_version = Gem::Version.new(ARGV[1] || '2.7.0')

puts "getting #{uri}"

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  puts '...'
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  http.request(request)
end
# error handling is boring so lets just assume this will always work
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
compatible = json.each_with_object({}) do |gem_version, hash|
  hash[gem_version["number"]] = gem_version["ruby_version"]
end.select do |gemv, rubyv|
  Gem::Requirement.new(rubyv)
                  .satisfied_by?(target_ruby_version)
end

puts "The following versions of #{gemname} satifisy the Ruby requirement #{target_ruby_version}:"

pp compatible.keys
```

However its actual usefulness for testing if a gem is actually compatible with a given version of Ruby is very questionable. Since authors don't usually specify a range of ruby versions it just tells you if the given Ruby version satisfies the minimum version requirement. Tom Lord does a very good job at describing why this is problematic.

Your experience with running Rails 0.8.0 on Ruby 2.7.0 may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Rails, and all other gems, can state a minimum required ruby version. This will be taken into consideration automatically when running `bundle update`.

However, there are two problems:

1. Library authors don't **always** do this perfectly -- so it's possible you might run a modern gem with an ancient ruby version, and only discover the incompatibility at runtime.
2. Library authors *cannot predict the future*; they might correctly specify a *minimum* required ruby version, but they cannot possibly know a *maximum* compatible ruby version in advance.

However, there is a silver lining: Ruby is pretty good at backwards compatibility. So unless you try to run a *big project* with ancient libraries and modern ruby (e.g. a rails 4 project using ruby 2.7), you're unlikely to have much problems here.

And also, as I suggest above, this is only likely to be an issue with *large gems*, such as the rails framework. [It's fairly well documented which minimum version of ruby is supported by each major rails release](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions):

> Rails 7 requires Ruby 2.7.0 or newer.
>
> Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5.0 or newer.
>
> Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

Comment: Most of the Ruby incompatibility issues in my experience are connected to gems that depend on external libraries like Nokogiri (and the schenanigans at 1 Infinite Loop).